What are grammatical features specific to Eurasia?
I'n curious about what typological/grammatical features are prevalent across the entirety of Eurasia but are rare or absent in the rest of the world. I'm aware of "Standard Average European" but this doesn't really answer my question as these features are not commonly present in the rest of Eurasia.
The inspiration for this question was an answer to another SE question where examples of where exotic grammatical features are located covered basically the entire world except for Eurasia, which makes me think that there must be some features of Eurasian languages that e.g. Papuan language speakers would find very odd, but linguists speaking Eurasian languages take for granted.

it doesn't answer your question, but you may be able to find answers yourself by looking at the various maps available on https://wals.info/ & https://grambank.clld.org/

The absence of ergative alignment is the most obvious that comes to mind. There are pockets of ergativity in Eurasia (Basque, various Indo-Aryan languages, and also in the far northeastern corner of Russia near Alaska), but it’s much rarer than in Oceania and the Americas. Then again, it’s equally – if not more – absent in Africa, so it’s not really unique to Eurasia (and it’s not like nominative–accusative alignment is absent in other parts of the world either).

@JanusBahsJacquet - Keep in mind the ergative heartland in the Caucasus-Mesopotamia region.
